# Keep track of what is on USB Devices

Tags: software-recommendation, usb

Is there any software that keeps track of the content of USB Devices I connect to my System? I have several (~15) USB-Sticks and I can't remember were I put certain files/pictures etc. Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep track of the content"? What output do you expect of it?

Comment: I mean files, documents, pictures, etc. saved on the usb device. Output could be a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) is an excellent solution for command line users. It keeps track of where your files are across local filesystems, external drives, different computers and cloud storage providers. [git-annex assistant](http://git-annex.branchable.com/assistant/) is a friendly front-end to it, but is still in development.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Gnome Catalog](http://www.gnomecatalog.org/) (package `gnomecatalog`)

Comment: Looks great, but no USB-Devices!

Comment: @konrad Just make sure you mount all of them on a descriptive location. E.g. mount USB stick #1 on `/media/usbstick01` and the catalog application will just index them there and makes it easy to identify the USB flash drive involved. I would suggest to ask a new question on how to mount them on specific location by device ID.

Comment: It may be easier to just change the location using the settings dialog every time you add a new device

Comment: I get error messages: TypeError: iglob() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
2013-01-24 15:43:36,336 [WARNING] factory(342): Please report this bug to the Freevo mailing list
2013-01-24 15:43:36,337 [ERROR] factory(341): kaa.metadata.create error

Answer (score 1):

If you like commandline tool try "mlocate".

It support file name search with "regular expression"

Using a switch you can specify custom database to search. This database can be created using `updatedb.mlocate` or `updatedb` (by specify location to index)

To cerate DB:
`updatedb -l 0 -o db_file -U source_directory`
Eg:`updatedb -l 0 -o /tmp/boot.db -U /boot/`

To search in the DB
`mlocate -id db_file file_to_search`

**examples**
Search for all files in DB boot.db
`mlocate -id /tmp/boot.db .*`

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mlocate -id /tmp/boot.db .*
>   /boot/System.map-3.5.0-17-generic
>   /boot/abi-3.5.0-17-generic
>   /boot/config-3.5.0-17-generic
>   /boot/memtest86+.bin
>   /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
>   /boot/grub/gfxblacklist.txt
>   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mlocate -id /tmp/boot.db -r .*
>   mlocate: non-option arguments are not allowed with --regexp
>   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mlocate -id /tmp/boot.db -r '.*'
>   /boot
>   /boot/System.map-3.5.0-17-generic
>   /boot/abi-3.5.0-17-generic
>   /boot/config-3.5.0-17-generic
>   /boot/grub
>   /boot/memtest86+.bin
>   /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
>   /boot/grub/gfxblacklist.txt
>   /boot/grub/grubenv
>   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

search for all files with extension *.cfg* using regular expression, ignore case
`mlocate -i -d /tmp/boot.db -r '.*\.cfg$'`

(see man page for more info such as switch)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you provide more information or links to explain how to use this?

Comment: @eliah-kagan : updated

Comment: updatedb for locate and updatedb.mlocate for mlocate.

Comment: By default they're both the same. The generic versions link to links in `/etc/alternatives` which link to the "m" versions. Do the commands still behave differently? They have the same manpage and it doesn't mention a difference in behavior stemming from how they are invoked... Anyway, can you edit your answer to explain *how to use `locate` and `mlocate`*?

Comment: Sure. I will, when i have access to my pc. Now i'm in a phone.

Comment: @eliah-kagan : updated